# Unable to extract a tag nested inside another tag using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have written the following code to get data from each product on the website https://www.1800wheelchair.com/category/369/transport-wheelchairs/?p=3, but there seems to be something wrong with it. It does not give any error, but also doesnt give the required output. My guess is that I am extracting the link of each product incorrectly, that is why it is not printing in output panel. I have been trying really long to figure this out, but not able to.

```
import requests
import xlsxwriter
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
def cpap_spider(max_pages):
    global row_i
    page=1
    while page<=max_pages:
        url= "https://www.1800wheelchair.com/category/369/transport-wheelchairs/?p=" +str(page)
        source_code= requests.get(url)
        plain_text= source_code.text
        soup= BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
        for link in soup.findAll("h2", {"class":"product-name"}):
            href=link.find("a")['href']
            title = link.string
            #worksheet.write(row_i, 0, title)
            #each_item(href)
            print(href)
            #print(title)
        page+=1

def each_item(item_url):
    global cols_names, row_i
    source_code= requests.get(item_url)
    plain_text= source_code.text
    soup= BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
    table=soup.find("table", {"class":"specifications "})
    if table:
        table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
    else:
        return
    for row in table_rows:
      cols = row.select('td')
      for ele in range(0,len(cols)):
        temp = cols[ele].text.strip()
        if temp:
          
          if temp[-1:] == ":":
            temp = temp[:-1]
          # Name of column
          if ele == 0:
            try:
              cols_names_i = cols_names.index(temp)
            except:
              cols_names.append(temp)
              cols_names_i = len(cols_names) -  1
              worksheet.write(0, cols_names_i + 1, temp)
              continue;
          worksheet.write(row_i, cols_names_i + 1, temp)      
    row_i += 1
    
cols_names=[]
cols_names_i = 0
row_i = 1
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('st.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write(0, 0, "Title")
    
cpap_spider(3)
    
workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain the correct results, set `User-Agent` HTTP header along your request:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.1800wheelchair.com/category/369/transport-wheelchairs/?p=3'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'
}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

for idx, a in enumerate(soup.select('a[itemprop="url"].button'), 1):
    print('{:<3} {}'.format(idx, a['href']))
```

Prints:

```
1   https://www.1800wheelchair.com/product/22-bariatric-aluminum-transport-chair/
2   https://www.1800wheelchair.com/product/lightweight-bariatric-transport-chair-63523/
3   https://www.1800wheelchair.com/product/medline-bariatric-transport-chair-with-12-rear-wheels/
4   https://www.1800wheelchair.com/product/karman-t-900-extra-wide-transport-wheelchair/
5   https://www.1800wheelchair.com/product/excel-freedom-plus-bariatric-transport-chair/
6   https://www.1800wheelchair.com/product/karman-removable-arm-transport-chair/
```

Comment: this works. I added the changes to both the functions, cpap_spider and each_item, it does not seem to work for the latter. I get the links in output, but my excel file is still blank. Is there something I am missing?